# Android Deveoplment

Tags: android, eclipse, android-mapview

I am a newbie in android development and am trying to make an android app to be submitted in 3 days. I was referring to [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview) for the purpose but stuck a dead end when I failed to find the so called HelloGoogleMaps.java in step 6 . All I found was Main Activity.java
Can some one guide me from here as I don't have much time and don't understand it.

Comment: what do you want to do with map activity?

Comment: @Shivaji I want to use the google map api in my app.

Comment: you might want to create the HelloGoogleMaps.java and insert some code(they might show the code in the tutorial) in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shagun

take look at this

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

Comment: Looks like the thing I wanted. Give me some time to go through it and then I will mark it as my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to be using the Google API's version of the API level that you wish to target/build for.

Comment: I have already checked that . Still thanks for answering